# c# panel getting cursor position

Tags: c#, cursor, panel

I'm making a panel with selectable items. This works perfectly at first but my panel is 45,000 pixels long and I cant select anything beyond 2^16/2(32,600 something). I'm getting the position relative to the panel, not the screen or program.

I'm currently using this code:

```
private void Panel_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Point screenPos = Panel.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);
    ...
}
```

I have also tried it as in the following code but it also doesn't work correctly, e.g. (at 30,000 pixels along the panel width it returns 58,404 and at 4,000 pixels down height it returns 7,032):

```
private void Panel_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Point screenPos = Panel.PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y));
    ....
}
```

Is there a way to use `cursor.Position` but with a bigger range?

**EDIT**
strangely when doing this in a MouseMove event it can return a value higher then 2^16/2

```
 private void Panel_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Point screenPos = Panel.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);
        Coordinate.Text = screenPos.ToString();

        ...
    }
```

this shows the correct value everywhere in my panel but even if i make screenPos a global variable and use that variable on my MouseClick event it doesnt work

**EDIT2**
Found that the issue is that MouseClick event doesnt work when values are that high(finding it a bit odd that it works with MouseMove tho). Now i've tried getting the latest coordinates from mousemove(which only updates when hovering the panel). Now i need to get another MouseClick Eventhandler, i tried it on the smaller pannel which holds the very big panel but this doesnt work. Also tried the handler on the entire Form but this only registers a click when im not clicking on any element so not on the panel.

Is there another solution for this?

Comment: You are running into a basic OS restriction, it [reports the mouse position](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645616(v=vs.85).aspx) in a 32-bit value with 16 bits each used to encode X and Y.  So a control must be smaller than short.MaxValue to stay usable.  32767 pixels.  It is not clear why such a big panel could be useful.  Focus on keeping your UI user-friendly, heavy duty scrolling never is.

Comment: @HansPassant but what about the second case where at 4,000 pixels along the Y axis it is returning a value of 7,032?  Is that just an effect of the internal calculation also using an incorrect figure for width?

Comment: Using PointToClient() is a bug, the reported mouse position is already in client coordinates.  Getting the absolute position ("screenpos") requires PointToScreen().

Comment: its required for me to have such a large panel, im using it as a map of a large area and i need to zoom in on it

Comment: when i use PointToScreen i get negative values

Comment: _its required for me to have such a large panel_ - Then don't use Winforms!